# How to make complex array combination from user input? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new to this field. So, currently, I want to make a simple feature for my website where if the user input like width and height value, the program will make an array that combines the two values but the other one is in alphabet form. So, for example, the user input `weight = 4,` and `height = 2`, I want the array to produce `[A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2]`. But, I got stuck in the part where combining those numbers and alphabet. As you can see from the snippet, I use for loop for most of the process. But, in the nested for loop, it will produce like `[A1, A12, A1, A12]` and so on. The alphabet is not changing and the number is stacking. I really need your help, Thank you!

```js
var askW = prompt('Enter width value');
var askH = prompt('Enter height value');
mapGenerator(askW, askH);

function mapGenerator(askW, askH){
    var w = Number(askW);
    var h = Number(askH);
    var containerW = [];
    var containerH = [];
    var initialCharValue = 64;
    var i;

    for (i = 64 ; i <= w + initialCharValue; i++){
        containerW.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }

    for (i = 1 ; i <= h; i++){
        containerH.push(i);
    }

    console.log(containerW);
    console.log(containerH);

    mapGenerator2(containerW, containerH);

    function mapGenerator2(containerW, containerH){
        var temparray = [];
        var repeated = [];
        var testArr = [];
        var i,j,a,b,chunk = 1;
        for (i=1,a=containerW.length; i<=a; i++) {
            temparray[i] = containerW.slice(i,i+chunk);
            repeated[i] = new Array(containerH.length).fill(temparray[i]).flat();
        }
        for (i=1, a = containerW.length; i<a ; i++){
            testArr = repeated[i].map(function(item) { 
              for(i=1, a = containerW.length; i<a ; i++){
                  console.log(item+= i);
              }
            console.log(testArr);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

P.S.: In the nested for loop, I use console.log because if I push the items into the array, it will like lagging and not logging console.

Comment: I really did not understand what is the relation between `width=4`, `height=2`, and `[A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,D2]` can you enlighten me about it? And how we should come up with that final array with those `width` and `height`.

Comment: Four letters with two numbers in each letter.

Comment: May I ask what you intend to do with the array?  When I saw **complex** in the question and combinations of letters and numbers, I immediately thought of a spreadsheet layout.  If that is the case, then an actual Map object may be better - as that will allow you to get/set values against each letter/number combination more easily.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your MapGenerator Function which shows the correct way of using nested for loops

```js
var askW = prompt('Enter width value');
var askH = prompt('Enter height value');
mapGenerator(askW, askH);

function mapGenerator(askW, askH){
    var w = Number(askW);
    var h = Number(askH);
    var containerW = [];
    var containerH = [];
    var initialCharValue = 64;
    var i;

    for (i = 64 ; i <= w + initialCharValue; i++){
        containerW.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }

    for (i = 1 ; i <= h; i++){
        containerH.push(i);
    }

    
    result = mapGenerator2(containerW, containerH);
    console.log(result)

    function mapGenerator2(containerW, containerH){
        var resultarray = [];        
        containerW.shift();
        containerW.forEach(function(itemW) {
           containerH.forEach(function(itemH) {
             resultarray.push(itemW + itemH.toString());
           })
        });
        
        return resultarray;
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create two loops that are nested the first loop will be in charge of the alphabet and the second will be in charge of the numbers like so:

```js
function mapGenerator2(height, width) {
  const result = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for(let j = 1; j <= height; j++) {
      result.push(`${String.fromCharCode(65 + i)}${j}`);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(mapGenerator2(2, 4));
```